# Which files are created/modified after install in Directus?

Tags: directus

I'm trying to install directus into Heroku.
Heroku reset files on the dyno every weeks, so every files need to be in git repository.
I would like to know which files are created/modified after install ?
I created and added /config/api.php but it's not enough it seems

Comment: If you're using the combined build `/config/api.php` should be enough. The only other things the API creates are logs in `/logs` and files in whatever directory you've specified for uploads. Why is it seemingly not enough?

Comment: Even with the /config/api.php file, i was stuck in the login/install part. I did a fresh install and now it seems to be fine. Now i have to configure a S3 bucket for files.